# Insert values greater than parameter in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Assume we have a linked List with with the following values {10,20,30,40,50} when a function is called with parameter 35 it returns a Linked List with the following values {10,20,30,40,50,40,50}.

So far this is what I did

```
public LinkedList insertHighersAtTheEnd(int target, LinkedList ls){
    Node current = head;
    while(current.getLink()!=null){

        if(current.getItem() < target)
            ls.add(current.getItem());

        else
            ls.add(-1);

        current = current.getLink();
    }
    return ls;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is how to write such a function that compares elements of the linked list to a parameter and then return all values larger than the parameter back to the linked list like the example shown above .